# Modify @JMSListener destination while building the app(not runtime)

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-jms, solace

I have developed a @JMSListener that gets the destination from Spring yml files and works just fine.

But now I would need to be able to change the "destination" of the queue on deployment time without having to reset the whole application

```
@Component
public class MyListener{

  //SOME_VARIABLES
 @JmsListener(destination = "${tibco.configuration.queues}")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
        //DO_SOME_STUFF
    }
```

In my application.yml and manifest.yml ,i have below

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-tibco-service-1
```

So when i buld the service  using my-tibco-service-1 ,tibco.configuration.queues= queue-100
when i buld the service  using my-tibco-service-2 ,tibco.configuration.queues= queue-101
when i buld the service  using my-tibco-service-3 ,tibco.configuration.queues= queue-102

Comment: Ehrm... How would making this during build easier then during runtime? Looks like you want to rebuild your whole app for a configuration change? That doesn't look like what you really want.

Comment: @M.Deinum I would have one source code .I would deploy teh code onPCF as 3 app .Only difference is each app would listen to 1 queue .And queue should be picked based on app name(or some other flag).I will have 3 builds i.e i will need to deploy code 3 times but this is ok

Comment: Just supply the name of the queue while deploying... It doesn't have to be in an `application.properties`. Looks like you are trying to fix a problem that isn't a problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you .How can i supply the queue name while deploying any idea?

Comment: You can use an environment variable, command line argument, additional `application.properties` next to the jar. All the possibilities are explained in the [Spring Boot guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)